# Inverting string-based binary number in one line in Python

Tags: code-golf, tips, python, bitwise

I want to read two strings on separate lines, each string the same length and containing only 0's and 1's, and determine if the first is the one's complement of the second.  How succinctly can this be done in Python3? (Sorry to specify the language, but this is for my son who's studying Python)

A list comprehension seems to work but is quite ugly.

```
if ['0' if x=='1' else '1' for x in input()] == list(input()): print('yep')
```

Is there a slicker/shorter way to do this?

Comment: Here's a simple, consice way: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzNNITEnR6NC0bZSIS2/SKFCp1IhM0@hKrNAIzOvoLREQ1MHSmtqWhUUZeaVaKhXphaoa/7/b2hgYMhlYGhoAAA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: If we're trying to do this for the shortest possible code, here's 52 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzNNITEnRyM3sUCjuKRILz4@LzU@Xiczr6C0REMTRmtqWhUUZeaVaKhXphaoa/7/b2hgYMhlYGhoAAA "Python 3 – Try It Online") But that isn't so clear.

Comment: Do you just want short code, or do you also want it to be elegant and/or readable?

Comment: Your example code will produce a syntax error, you can't have `then` without an `else`, perhaps you meant to use `:`? Removing spaces gets you `if['0'if x=='1'else'1'for x in input()]==list(input()):print('yep')` for 67 bytes, but that can be improved upon.

Comment: @JonathanAllan You simply can't have `then`, whether you have an `else` or not.

Comment: @Steffan is right, `then` won't work :)

Comment: Thanks guys.  I tried my code, noticed the error and fixed it, but forgot to fix it in my question above.  Edited my question to correct it!

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/),  <s>51 44 43</s>  41 bytes

-7 thanks to [loopy walt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/107561/loopy-walt)'s suggestion to use `*open`.
-1 thanks to [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor)'s suggestion to replace `any(...)` with `1in ...`
-2 thanks to [dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546/dingledooper)'s suggestion of using `str.find` instead of `str.__eq__`

```python
0in map(str.find,*open(0))or print('yep')
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/3yAzTyE3sUCjuKRILy0zL0VHK78gNU/DQFMzv0ihoCgzr0RDvTK1QF3z/39DAyDkAhEGAA)**

This is a full program that takes input from stdin until an EOF (which we assume the user provides at the end of the second line) with `open(0)` and `map`s across the two strings by splatting (`*`), calling `str.find` on each pair of characters in turn. If `0` is `in` the result (i.e. the characters are equal and so the index of the first in the second is `0` rather than `-1` for "not found") then the right-hand clause of the `or` is not evaluated, and so we don't `print`.

---

My previous version, with xnor's and dingledooper's suggestions, at \$48\$, is interactive without the EOF faff:

```python
0in map(str.find,input(),input())or print('yep')
```

---

You *could* save one more byte by printing to stderr instead of stdout by exiting the program early using `exit` in place of `print`.

---

A note to your son - this is not how I'd want someone in my team at work to write code :) - readability counts, a lot.

Comment: Don't you mean unless any of the pairs are equal to each other?

Comment: @Neil thanks, I got there in the end :p (many edits)

Comment: `any(map(str.__eq__,*open(0)))or print('yep')`

Comment: @loopywalt Oh yeah, I always wondered - how does that know when to stop taking input? Is it EOF?

Comment: Good question, actually. Perhaps CTRL-D? (Just a wild guess.)

Comment: Windows seems to need CtrlZ <return> CtrlZ <return> - :/ :o

Comment: On Linux, Ctrl+D seems to work.

Comment: Ctrl+Z <enter> works fine on Windows. You just need to make sure you suffix the previous input with a newline, or the Ctrl+Z is included as part of that input.

Comment: @Steffan Tried that but it produced no output for me, while the double use with no newline worked.

Comment: Yes, it seems to only work if you finish the previous input. So <enter> Ctrl+Z <enter>. (relevent: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16136924/10914124)

Comment: @Steffan nope, that does not work, but typing `\n` at the end of the second line does (facepalm). EDIT or indeed an `x` :/

Comment: that's exactly what I said lol. edit: wait, you mean literally typing a backslash and `n`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139737/discussion-between-jonathan-allan-and-steffan).

Comment: `print(all(map(str.__ne__,*open(0)))*'yep')` saves another 2 but prints an empty line in case of failure.

Comment: Looks like the `any(...)` can be `1in ..`

Comment: @loopywalt I thought of that, but don't think it's really in keeping with the intention.

Comment: 41 bytes: `0in map(str.find,*open(0))or print('yep')`.

Comment: Nice one @dingledooper :)

Comment: Aside: `stdin` , `stdout`, and `stderr` are each just single words, there're no internal spaces.

Comment: @Noodle9 - updated.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 62 bytes

Since the bits at the similar position need to be set in one of the inputs and unset in the other, their bitwise XOR must have all bits set.

```python
x=input()
int(x,2)^~-(1<<len(x))^int(input(),2)or print("yep")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8I2M6@gtERDkyszr0SjQsdIM65OV8PQxiYnNU@jQlMzDiQMVQKUzC9SKCgCCSlVphYoaf7/b2hgaGjAZWBoYGAIAA)

*-5 bytes thanks to Arnauld*

Updated from my previous answer where I incorrectly assumed that checking bitwise AND = 0 was a sufficient condition.

Comment: [62 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8I2M6@gtERDkyszr0SjQsdIM65OV8PQxiYnNU@jQlMzDiQMVQKUzC9SKCgCCSlVphYoaf7/b2hgaGjAZWBoYGAIAA)